# Unable to call sendMail function in grails application

Tags: grails

I am trying to call send mail in grails.  I am calling from a controller

```
class TournamentController {
    static scaffold = true
    //controller functions


    def emailParticipants(Tournament t) {
        def emailSubject = "Tournament ${t.title} complete"

        for (Prediction p : t.predictions){
            if (p.email != null){
                def emailBody = """\
                    Hello ${p.name}!  Thank you for participating in the ${t.title} tournament.
                    Please find a link below with statistics and match results.
                    """
                sendMail {
                    async true
                    to p.email
                    subject emailSubject
                    body emailBody
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is a MissingMethodException with the following message:

```
No signature of method: predictionpal.MailService.sendMail() is applicable for
argument types(predictionpal.TournamentController$_emailParticipants_closure2)
values
[predictionpal.TournamentController$_emailParticipants_closure2@51fc1bbb]
Possible solutions: findAll()
```

Here is what I added to BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    //There is a stuff I didn't add here

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // **I ONLY ADDED THIS LINE**
        compile ":mail:1.0.7"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.18" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" 
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ":console:1.5.3"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

I have tried doing

```
grails stop-app
grails clean
grails run-app
```

but my issue was still not fixed.

Comment: What is the correct information in your BuildConfig.groovy. Seems the mail plugin is not installed http://grails.org/plugin/mail or not compiled

Comment: It seems to be calling MailService as it should, but it says that there are no method called sendMail that accepts a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `mailService` bean in your controller class:

```
class TournamentController {
    static scaffold = true

    def mailService // Inject the bean

    def emailParticipants(Tournament t) {
    def emailSubject = "Tournament ${t.title} complete"

    for (Prediction p : t.predictions){
        if (p.email != null){
            def emailBody = """\
                Hello ${p.name}!  Thank you for participating in the ${t.title} tournament.
                Please find a link below with statistics and match results.
                """
            mailService.sendMail { // Use the bean's sendMail method
                async true
                to p.email
                subject emailSubject
                body emailBody
            }
```

Comment: OK so my problem was that I had previously created a Service called MailService.  In that MailService there was no function for sendMail.  I reverted to an old commit before I created the service and did it the way you (and the mail plugin documentation) suggested and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help!